# Swift class properties not initialized when constructed by Objective C code

Tags: objective-c, swift, cordova, swift3

I'm attempting to create a class in Swift 3 to implement a Cordova plugin.  I have this building and running, but the application crashes whenever any properties of the class are accessed.  I've tried two ways of initializing the class:

```
@objc(DSFMediaCentre)
class DSFMediaCentre : CDVPlugin
{
    var players = [UUID:DSFPlayerHandler] ();
    ...
}
```

and

```
@objc(DSFMediaCentre)
class DSFMediaCentre : CDVPlugin
{
    var players :[UUID:DSFPlayerHandler];
    override init () {
        players = [:];
    }
    ...
}
```

However, when my `players` property is used, the result is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception, with an address that looks like a null pointer dereference.

The object is being created by Objective C code, which is a language I have no familiarity with at all, but I think this is the line that creates it:

```
obj = [[NSClassFromString(className)alloc] initWithWebViewEngine:_webViewEngine];
```

The `CDVPlugin` class contains a comment stating that `initWithWebViewEngine` should not be overridden (and indeed I do not seem to be *able* to override this method, because while it is declared in the `CDVPlugin.m` file, it isn't mentioned in `CDVPlugin.h`, so the Swift compiler doesn't seem to know about it), but rather initialization code should be placed in a method called `pluginInitialize` instead. However, if I do that I get a compiler error ("Class DSFMediaCentre has no initializers").

Furthermore, if I put my `init()` method back in and set it to call `pluginInitialize()`, like this:

```
override init () {
    super.init();    // necessary otherwise next line is an error
    pluginInitialize(); 
}
override func pluginInitialize() {
    players = [:];
}
```

the error then changes to "Property 'self.players' not initialized at super.init call".

How do I make this class initialize correctly?

Comment: Perhaps you're using Swift 4, and need to prefix the class + ivars that are accessed from Objective-C with @objc?

Comment: No, I'm using swift 3.  Will add that to the question; haven't even looked at swift 4 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mismatch between the strict initialization system required by the language and the procedure used by the framework you're working with.

Swift demands that a) properties be initialized as part of object construction, and b) that construction be chained to the type's supertype. But the `CDVPlugin` type is doing the construction on your behalf; you don't have the ability to customize it. (This makes more sense in ObjC, because it doesn't have the same compile-time restrictions as Swift.)

The situation is similar to unpacking an object from a nib file. In that case too, because it's the nib loading system that's constructing your object, you don't have the ability to customize the initializer. Your type will always be constructed by `init(coder:)`. In a certain sense, your initialization point moves further down, to `awakeFromNib()`, and among other things, that forces outlets to other objects in the archive to be declared as optional, usually implicitly unwrapped.

The same solution should avail you here. You should consider `pluginInitialize()` to be your initialization point. The language then requires that properties be optional, since they are not filled at *its* initialization point. Therefore, make the property an IUO:

```
@objc(DSFMediaCentre)
class DSFMediaCentre : CDVPlugin
{
    var players :[UUID:DSFPlayerHandler]!
    override func pluginInitialize() {
        players = [:];
    }
}
```

and all should be well.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution is to use lazy keyword

```
   lazy var players :[UUID:DSFPlayerHandler] = [:]
```

So, you don't need to initialize players in initializer but still make sure players always non-nulable